# Multi-year and multi-location correlation or regression?

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, multivariate-analysis

I have **fire activity** data (*i.e.* number of fires) and a series of factors (*e.g.* **precipitation**, **tree cover loss**, **distance to nearest forest**, etc...) that can potentially explain it. I have all this data for different locations for each year between 2002 and 2016.

I am trying to find the factors that can better explain the ocurrence of fires but I am not sure what is the best way to statistically achieve this. My first approach would be to do a (multiple) correlation or maybe even a linear regression. However, how would I approach this situation, taking into account that I have yearly observations for my data?

I guess I could do 15 different regressions (one for each year) but I don't want to interpret the results separately, as my main goal is to identify the factors that better explain fire activity altogether, regardless of the year. I read about multivariate linear regressions and how they can take more than one outcome variable but I am not sure if they would fit my purpose. Should I just merge all of my data and forget about the time dimension?

Comment: When you have time series data as you do ... you should be aware of the assumptions of ordinary regression. Take a long and close look at this http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/regvsbox-old.pdf piece that I wrote a few years back.

Comment: I don't think it is advisable to run a regression for each year. I would analyze each location by itself and then look for commonality across models.

Comment: @IrishStat Thanks for the pdf, I will definitely read it. Would you analyze each location independently even when the number of locations is approximately 100,000?

Answer (score 0):

I would analyze each site separately to be able to draw some conclusions about the form of temporal dependence ... If it was slight then I would pool all the data after having adjusted for any evidented outliers/unusual values.

Comment: This misses the spirit of the question, which focuses on the potential for *spatial* correlation.  Forest fires spread, inducing such correlation; and the potential for fires is based on the availability of fuel, prevailing wind directions, and many other factors with strong spatial correlations.